# Do we need to generate stubs while writing a JAX WS client

Tags: jax-ws, marshalling, unmarshalling, stub

While we write a EJB client we need to generate EJB stub classes based on the EJB Remote interface. These stub classes are resposible to serialize/deserialize the object parameters and return values.

When we use a JAX WS client, do we still need to generate stub classes to marshall and unmarshall Java <--> XML?

Or will it be done by the Websphere JAX WS implementation classes somehow automatically under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you need something extra to convert the XML message ([SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) message) to Java object and viceversa, you don't.

JAX-WS converts the incoming SOAP message (actually a XML request) to Java object. And transforms the Java objects to XML response for send to the web service client.

[image: SOAP Message]
<sub>(source: [anyframejava.org](http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/cxf-jaxws/4.5.3/reference/image/cxf-jaxws/webservices/jaxws.jpg))</sub>

The conversion in both directions is performed by [JAXB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXB).

See more in [*Developing Web Services Applications*](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4884.html).

Comment: the class that converts from java-->soap needs to be generated by me? or is it packaged already in the jax ws implementation?